# GCP DataProc Serverless - VPC/subnet/firewall requirements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networkx, serverless, dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I'm trying my first GCP Dataproc Serverless PySpark batch job, which needs to connect to a public REST endpoint, and write to a GCS bucket in the same GCP project. After having submitted, the job was in PENDING state for awhile, and then failed with this error

> StructuredError{spark, Timed out waiting for at least 1 worker(s) registered. This is often caused by firewall rules that prevent Spark workers from communicating with the master. Please review your network firewall rules and be sure they allow communication on all ports between all nodes. See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/network for instructions

In that guide, I could not understand the purpose of the section `Open subnet connectivity`.

Where are the master and workers running? Aren't they all in a separate VPC managed by GCP, why should I need to worry about the connectivity among them? What should I put in `network-name` and `SUBNET_RANGES` mentioned in that guide?

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-internal-ingress \
--network=network-name \
--source-ranges=SUBNET_RANGES \
--direction=ingress \
--action=allow \
--rules=all
```

Comment: If you already have the "default" VPC Network with default Firewall rules, you should not get that error message. So if you already didn't , go to the console and call the "VPC Network" service, it should ask you to enable the compute engine API etc.. at the end you should see the the default VPC..

Comment: Error indicates that your VPC's internal IP addresses are not connected to one another. A firewall rule added as indicated in the document should be helpful:

Comment: As Emre mentioned, that error notice shouldn't appear if your VPC network is already set up as the "default" one with the default firewall rules. You can also try this --network="network-name" \\  --source-ranges="subnetwork internal-IP ranges" ,which may help to resolve your issue.